How to get confirmation that a SMS is sent? (python-gammu)
Im develoiping an application with python-gammu (mainly). It's working fine, treating errors and logging, but there's a flaw in it:
Im not able to catch an exception when it occurs after the message is sent.
For example: If I send a SMS and something happens during the process of the SMS getting to the user, I'm not able to know. Is there any way to get confirmation that the SMS was sent to the final user, that it actually got to their device?
I tried to find a python-gammu function for it but wasn't able to.
